# How would I remove all the zeros before the 1 in this python list

Tags: python, list, loops

```
result = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

I want this list to be turned into

```
result = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

I have tried using a while loop to keep removing zeros until it finds a 1 but I cant seem to get that to work.

```
for x in result:
    while (x == 0):
        result.remove(0)
```

Comment: Will there always be at least one 1?

Answer (score 3):

If there always is a 1, you could just find it and delete everything before it:

```
del result[:result.index(1)]
```

Or if it could be all zeros:

```
if any(result):
    del result[:result.index(1)]
```

or

```
try:
    del result[:result.index(1)]
except ValueError:
    pass
```

or

```
result.append(1)
del result[:result.index(1)]
result.pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `itertools.dropwhile`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

list(dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, result))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your code is you are changing the list while iterating. Instead you can use while loop.

```
while result and result[0] == 0:
    result.pop(0)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or else try the following :

```
result = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
a=''
for i in result:
    a=a+str(i)
print(list(a.lstrip('0')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

# prints index of 1st (leftmost) '1' encountered in the list
# print(result.index(1)) 

# print from that index to the wholw remaining list
print(result[result.index(1):])
```